# Do multiple treatments represent a single categorical factor, or multiple, for determining 1-way or 2-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova

I have a dataset for 4 treatments (control, fertiliser A, fertiliser B, fertiliser A+B). I have assumed these treatments represent a single categorical factor, and therefore conducted a 1-way ANOVA, however, I now have the seed of doubt that I'm making a mistake. Any advice/reassurance would be appreciated.

Comment: 1-way ANOVA with 4 levels is correct in my opinion. I don't see how you could extract two factors from your design.